# Perl web-service (server) best practices

Tags: perl, web-services, authentication, ssl, authorization

I'm currently using a modified [HTTP::Daemon::Threaded](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Daemon::Threaded) server in
combination with SOAP::WSDL and [Pod::WSDL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Pod::WSDL) to provide web services
used by a variety of client types and roles.

---- that's not the question, the following is -----

I'd like to arrive at an optimal solution (as far as is possible) with respect to the following topics:

- Request/Dispatch/Response speed
- Protocol security (proper use of client-authenticated SSLv3/TLS)
- Resource security (security roles/traits on per-resource & per-method bases)
- Declarative specification of types, method signatures, and required security roles & traits.

Questions:

1. I'd like to be using an [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Select) or [IO::Async::Loop::IO_Ppoll](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Async::Loop::IO_Ppoll) -based server, but I understand that this is not compatible with in-server client authenticated SSL. **Is my understanding correct?**
2. I'd like to move away from verifying the client certificate on each request, to something like CA SiteMinder, where I give out a time-limited session cookie after successful client certificate verification, which can be used on subsequent requests to avoid this time penalty (and to lessen server load). **Is this going to be as secure?** (or even good enough?)
3. Is there some module/framework I can build on to provided Trait and Role -based Authorisation for the exposed object and methods. Pod::WSDL really only deals with types (and not even complex ones). I'd like to use/implement some declarative annotation (or external YAML) -based scheme to handle complex WSDL typing as well as Trait & Role Authorisation. **Has anyone done this?** (even separately?) **Are there any other modules which might be a good starting point?**
4. Finally - **Am I just crazy for doing this in Perl5 ?** ;)

Comment: Why are you writing a server yourself? Is there something special you need to do that another server like apache or lighttpd can't do for you?

Comment: The server part was the easy part. Perhaps I should have put even more emphasis on the security and authorisation topics in my post.

I trialled a bunch of server configurations, with servers including Apache, lighthttpd, and NginX, HTTP::Daemon, and HTTP::Daemon::Threaded.

Comment: (contintued) ... With my existing (threaded) codebase (some apartment, some actorish) I found the most optimal solution speed-wise is HTTP::Daemon::Threaded once you take startup/dispatch into account for the "another server" cases.

But really, that's secondary. I only included that information so as to constrain the discussion for the topics I did ask about: Security, Declarative WSDL Typing & Authorisation, and lastly (but not ruling out) request/dispatch/response speed.

Comment: @David: That didn't really clarify anything for me. With just what you've said in the post and comments, it still sounds like stuff either apache or lighthttpd can easily handle. I've written lots of weird auth schemes for those. Is it just the threaded perl that driving most of this decision?

Comment: Then perhaps you could point to examples. I don't understand what advantage apache or lighthttpd give me in "Declarative WSDL Typing & Authorisation". Do they have some pre-built SOAP oriented infrastructure that I can use for a loosely typed language like Perl ? I'm quite aware that any server can do the SSL part. My question wrt security was about using a Cookie to avoid constantly re-verifying an SSL client certificate.

Comment: I think perhaps I'll have more luck if I break these issues out into separate SO questions, perhaps without mentioning server issues, which just aren't important. I only mentioned the server at all in case that constrained my options wrt to the real topics, but noone has even begun to address those topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, everyone's answering everything but the real questions.

I'll break this out into specific questions in separate posts, and won't make any mention at all of the server make-up - a topic which everyone in this thread seems to want to discuss, and which is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but FYI `IO::Async` will work just fine with SSL, ever since the [`IO::Async::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aAsync%3a%3aSSL) module.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for that. I did (much later) find this to be the case. A little difficult to follow up on questions of this type though, because at the time noone saw the value of implementing server infrastructure efficiently in composable ways (roles now filled by Plack, Starman, etc). You couldn't ask the question without being flooded with irrelevant "you're re-inventing a perfectly good wheel" sort of answers/comments.

Answer (score -5):

You're crazy for doing this in Perl :-)

Seriously though, more power to you.  My question is, presuming you have some reason to reinvent this wheel, is why not consider Python?  Perl is alive and well but so much of this kind of thing (low level scripting) is being done in Python now.

Finally, presuming you don't have an actual reason to be doing this (aside from fun), you should really consider a Web Framework (Django of course) and something like nginx to handle the HTTP interaction.

Comment: This is not for fun.

This an attempt to modernise an existing infrastructure while re-using thousands previously written Perl modules.

In any case, does Django automatically give me the kind of Authorisation infrastructure that I asked about?

I do use NginX for static HTTP content. I've found that the (threaded) pure-perl server is just as fast, and a lot more flexible. The nearest alternative is NginX + FastCGI with a threaded dispatcher... which is really the same thing at the end of the day, except that now I have to deal with an external system to do client cert verification.

Comment: After looking at the Django docs - perhaps I'm missing something - I can't see where any of the declarative WSDL typing and Role+Trait Authorisation is possible, let alone available.

Are there contributed libraries that do this, or at least provide a place to start from? 

I'm not ruling out doing this part in another language (like Python), after all I could proxy the final requests to my existing server - as long as it doesn't cost too much.

Comment: I'd consider Perl and Python to be equivalent tools in this case. Maybe Perl has an edge with CPAN, but Python isn't going to be able to do something you can't get with Perl (or even Ruby).

Comment: David,  Django will give you access to the HTTP information for doing HTTP authentication, and then you'll have to plug it into some sort of authentication mechanism ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META ).  Or, you can use their built in authentiçation ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ ).

Then, use FLUP as the cgi service to connect to nginx.  Nginx doesn't speak wsgi so that won't be an option if you want to use nginx.

Comment: And, keep in mind that with Django, you still have the entire Python (2.6) stack for the low level stuff.  Django just gives you best practices methods for doing all the common web stuff.

Comment: David - I just reread your first comment.  Is there a reason you're concerned about speed so much?  Is this for some super low powered embedded system or something?  This is a list of possible HTTP servers to use in a Python stack (if you need customized HTTP services or something). http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Servers

Comment: @Adam. I'm concerned about speed because we get a lot of requests and would like to be able to make efficient use of the 3 machines currently servicing these requests before adding two more. I think everyone in the thread is getting hung up on the HTTP server stuff. Please don't. My questions are about 1. Dispatch Speed, (in the face of) 2. SSL client verification (that I don't want to have to do on each request), while at the same time adding 3. Declarative WSDL complex typing & role+trait security for resources exposde by the webservices.